# How do I run a query to transform desired rows into columns based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have 26 sensors set to periodically log data to my DB. Every 10 ms, the "Val" column has 26 values added, with respective tag index next to it (see "Current Table" below). I am looking to run a query which lists the tag indexes as columns, with their values underneath ordered by time (see "Desired Transformation"). It is easy to pull all values of a single tag index as a column and order by time, but I want to do this for multiple indexes and list them next to each other. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!!!!

Current Table:

```
**DateAndTime   TagIndex    Val**
DateAndTime 1   TagIndex 0  Val 1
DateAndTime 1   TagIndex 1  Val 2
DateAndTime 1   TagIndex 2  Val 3
      ……    ……  ……
DateAndTime 1   TagIndex n  Val n
DateAndTime 2   TagIndex 0  Val n+1
DateAndTime 2   TagIndex 1  Val n+2
DateAndTime 2   TagIndex 2  Val n+3
      ……    ……  ……
DateAndTime m   TagIndex n  Val m
```

Desired Transformation

```
**DateAndTime   TagIndex 0  TagIndex 1  TagIndex 2  ……. TagIndex n**
DateAndTime 1   Val 1   Val 2   Val 3   ……  Val n
DateAndTime 2   Val n+1 Val n+2 Val n+3 ……  Val 2
……  ……  ……  ……  ……  ……
DateAndTime m   ……  ……  ……  ……  Val m
```

Comment: Google for "pivot table" in SQL Server.  A basic pivot query should work fine, assuming the number of columns is always fixed.  As for performance, I don't know what you're looking for here.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Or dinamyc pivot. But looksl like the 26 sensor are fixed.

Comment: You could at least explain what the screenshots are. But they shouldn't be screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **dynamic** pivot table.
I don't know what your table name is , so put your table name in `YourTableName`

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(TagIndex)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TagIndex FROM YourTableName) AS TagIndex

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT DateAndTime, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM YourTableName
    PIVOT(SUM(Val)
          FOR TagIndex IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! Follow up question: How do I organize it so that the TagIndex increases from left to right? In other words, order the columns by TagIndex

Comment: Now how would I order the rows by the DateAndTime column (first one which stays fixed?